# PHP Website: Export <table> to Excel - And strip <img> and <a> tags

Tags: javascript, php

I currently have a working Excel export from a  to a downloadable excel file.
However, in my table (on the website) the contents of cells links to a seperate system (Listing customers in a table, and the link wrapped around the customer name will take you to our CRM and onto the customer). Also in the last column I have two images that acts as buttons/links to change a value in that row.

However I dont want these links and images exported into the Excel - I just want the contents of the cells.

Heres the code (javascript / jquery.table2excel.js):

```
//table2excel.js
(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {
    var pluginName = "table2excel",
            defaults = {
            exclude: ".noExl",
            name: "Table2Excel"
    };

    // The actual plugin constructor
    function Plugin ( element, options ) {
            this.element = element;
            // jQuery has an extend method which merges the contents of two or
            // more objects, storing the result in the first object. The first object
            // is generally empty as we don't want to alter the default options for
            // future instances of the plugin
            this.settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );
            this._defaults = defaults;
            this._name = pluginName;
            this.init();
    }

    Plugin.prototype = {
        init: function () {
            var e = this;
            e.template = "<html xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>";
            e.template += "<x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions>";
            e.template += "<x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>";
            e.tableRows = "";

            // get contents of table except for exclude
            $(e.element).find("tr").not(this.settings.exclude).each(function (i,o) {
                e.tableRows += "<tr>" + $(o).html() + "</tr>";
            });
            this.tableToExcel(this.tableRows, this.settings.name);
        },
        tableToExcel: function (table, name) {
            var e = this;
            e.uri = "data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,";
            e.base64 = function (s) {
                return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)));
            };
            e.format = function (s, c) {
                return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) {
                    return c[p];
                });
            };
            e.ctx = {
                worksheet: name || "Worksheet",
                table: table
            };
            window.location.href = e.uri + e.base64(e.format(e.template, e.ctx));
        }
    };

    $.fn[ pluginName ] = function ( options ) {
            this.each(function() {
                    if ( !$.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName ) ) {
                            $.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ) );
                    }
            });

            // chain jQuery functions
            return this;
    };

})( jQuery, window, document );
```

**Update 1:**

Did not work replacing
e.tableRows += "" + $(o).**html**() + "";
with
e.tableRows += "" + $(o).**text**() + "";
The result was that the tags were indeed stripped, but all columns got merged into one single column.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to strip out the offending elements by changing this code:

```
e.tableRows += "<tr>" + $(o).html() + "</tr>";
```

to this:

```
e.tableRows += "<tr>" + $(o).html().replace(/<a.+?<\/a>|<img.+?>/g, '') + "<tr>";
```

The other option would be to create a second table with `display: none` without the features you don't need, and act on that table in your export script.

Comment: Close, but no cigar! This gave me only the text, and not the html. Which is good. But all columns is merged into one column. Instead of having: Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 - i now get: Column 1Column 2Column 3

Comment: All right then. I changed my answer to strip any `<a>` and `<img>` tags while leaving the rest of the html in the row intact.

Comment: Darnit - did not work that either. Now my first row (column headers) gets exported, in separate columns. So far so good. But none of the other 750 table rows is included in the excel file downloaded :/

Comment: The display: none; way worked, but it makes me do a second SQL query and its a bit messy imo. Would prefer the striptags/replace way.

Comment: The code above shouldn't have changed the loop logic. Did you check your console for errors?

Comment: Well it only gives me the first row (the only row without the a href and img tags. This is the output in console when exporting: Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/vnd.ms-excel: "data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,PGh0bWwgeG1sbnM6bz0idXJuOnNjaGVtYXMtbW…RkIGFsaWduPSJjZW50ZXIiPjwvdGQ+CgkJCQkJCTx0cj48L3RhYmxlPjwvYm9keT48L2h0bWw+".